# Groovy 1.8 a b c style

Tags: groovy, dsl

I need help with one of the Groovy 1.8 DSL features.

Consider [this](http://svn.codehaus.org/groovy/trunk/groovy/groovy-core/src/test/gls/syntax/Gep3Test.groovy) test case:

```
/**
 * For odd number of elements, treat the last element as a call to a getter
 *
 * case            a b  c
 * equivalent      a(b).getC()
 */
void testTrailingElementAsGetter() {
    def drank = false
    def more = 'more'
    def drink = { String s -> [milk: { drank = true }()] }

    def d = drink more milk

    assert drank
}
```

If I change `[milk: { drank = true }()]` to `[foo: { drank = true }()]`, the test case still passes. Could this be a bug in the new implementation or am I missing something in the Groovy syntax?

**EDIT - SOLVED**: Both @han and @Gareth Davis posted the right clues. Here are some more details to understand this test:

```
    groovy:000> more = 'more'
    ===> more 
    groovy:000> drank = false 
    ===> false
    groovy:000> drink = { String s -> [milk: { drank = true }()] }
    ===> groovysh_evaluate$_run_closure1@20c87621
[A] groovy:000> drink more
    ===> {milk=true}    
[B] groovy:000> drank  
    ===> true          
    groovy:000> drink more milk
    ===> true
    groovy:000> drink more water
    ===> null
```

Line `[A]` returns a map as @han pointed out. In line `[B]`, `drank` is already `true`, due to the closure executing immediately after creation (as @Gareth Davis pointed out), similar to the [JavaScript module pattern](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2007/06/12/module-pattern/). I don't think this "test" is the best way to showcase this feature - the side-effect on `drank` is mis-leading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
groovy:000> drank =false
===> false
groovy:000> d = {x -> [y: {drank=true}()]}
===> groovysh_evaluate$_run_closure1@170b819
groovy:000> drank
===> false
groovy:000> d 2  
===> {y=true}
groovy:000> drank
===> true
```

x on first invoke sets drank to true then becomes just a map {y : true}

quite a puzzling behaviour really

from this we can see
there are many ways to synthesize a DSL from the new 1.8 syntax
- key-dereferencing maps
- closure and call
- class and method

be bary

Answer (score 2):

the problem is in:

```
def drink = { String s -> [milk: { drank = true }()] }
```

change to:

```
def drink = { String s -> [milk: { drank = true }] }
```

The trailing parens where actually calling the closure on creation rather than on running the DSL.

```
def d = drink more milk

// d is actually a closure not a boolean you would need to invoke it in order to get the required side effect of setting drank.
d.call()
```